# How to style every anchor element inside of dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

```
          <div
            className={classes.htmlAnswer}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: faq.html_answer }}
            style={{
              a:{
                textDecoration:'none',
                color:'gold',
              }
            }}
          />
```

I am using Material UI and React JS.

Inside of the dangerouslySetInnerHTML, I want every anchor element that appears to receive the styling. How can I do this? The code above doesn't work.

Comment: You'll either need to use CSS via a `<style>` or a separate stylesheet, or something like [`html-react-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) to replace the `a` nodes' style attributes with your style.

Comment: you can use this library rather use dangerousHtml https://www.npmjs.com/package/interweave